# Facebook Unity SDK login problems

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

When using the Facebook Unity SDK for Unity3D Android, I find that I have to pick my poison when the user is trying to login to FB from my game.

FB App is installed:

```
    FB_PERMISSIONS = "basic_info,publish_actions" // works
    FB_PERMISSIONS = "public_profile,user_friends,publish_actions"; // App goes from landscape to portrait, flashes a dialog and changes back to landscape. Login fails.
```

FB App NOT installed (uses webview login dialog):

```
    FB_PERMISSIONS = "basic_info,publish_actions" // fails: "Invalid Scope: basic_info. Use public_profile, user_friends instead"
    FB_PERMISSIONS = "public_profile,user_friends,publish_actions"; // works
```

I am using the FB Unity SDK 5.1.0. I notice that games like Subway Surfers forces webview regardless of whether the FB app is installed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using just **"user_friends,publish_actions"**?

The "public_profile" permission seems to be granted automatically.
I can't test this right now so please, let me know if it works.